# C++ Address of this is different when passed to function

Tags: c++

I have a very interesting observation that may or may not be expected. I have two very complicated classes that each extend many other unrelated classes. For reference, one is a socket and one is a virtual device. During construction of the virtual device, I want to pass the address of the device to the a socket object. The socket object is also part of the virtual device. It basically looks like this

```
class TcpSocket : public Socket, public OtherThing {
    void Init(OtherOtherClass *device){
        printf("0x%x\n", device); //0x1aaaf794
    }
};
​
class Device : public OtherClass, public OtherOtherClass {
    Device(){
        printf("0x%x\n", this); //0x1aaaf6d0
        this->socket.Init(this);
        printf("0x%x\n", this); //0x1aaaf6d0
    }
    TcpSocket socket;
};
```

I *cannot* reproduce this in a sandbox environment, but when I print out the addresses, they are different. So maybe I will just ask the question.

In function `TcpSocket::Init` it is expecting an `OtherOtherClass*` and not a `Device*`. Is this the reason why the address appears to be different?

Comment: So what happens when you replace "OtherOtherClass *device" with "Device *device"?

Comment: Good idea. I will try it out.

Comment: Other views of the same underlying phenomenon: [Q: More than 1 address for derived class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776469/more-than-1-address-for-derived-class-object) and [A: About dynamic cast and address of base and derived objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005389/about-dynamic-cast-and-address-of-base-and-derived-objects/6005442#6005442)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

`Device` has several base classes. When converting a `Device*` pointer to a `OtherOtherClass*` pointer, the value will be different since the new pointer will be pointing at the instance of `OtherOtherClass` within the instance of `Device`.

Answer (score 3):

Class Inheritance is an "is-a" relationship. `Device` contains everything that is in `OtherClass`, and everything is that in `OtherOtherClass`.  So, a `Device` object *is also* an `OtherClass` object, and *is also* an `OtherOtherClass` object.

When you have a `Device*` pointer (or `Device&` reference) to a `Device` object, it points/refers to the `Device` portion of the object.  And when you have an `OtherOtherClass*` pointer (or `OtherOtherClass&` reference) to a `Device` object, it points/refers to the `OtherOtherClass` portion of the object.  And the same with `OtherClass`.

That is why you see a different memory address being reported in `TcpSocket::Init()` than you do in `Device::Device()`.  You have two pointers to *different portions* of the *same object*.

Comment: I've always thought of it as the exact opposite! A `Device` object *isn't* a `OtherOtherClass`, so when a `OtherOtherClass*` is wanted you can't directly use a `Device*`, because nothing will be where it needs to be. A `Device` does always contain an `OtherOtherClass`, so you can always offset the `Device*` to select the `OtherOtherClass` subobject within the object you've got. The "is-a" relationship is a fiction/abstraction that makes sense when designing the classes because the conversion is automatic, but I find it useful to remember that the actual language doesn't quite work that way.

Comment: A `Device` *is-a* `OtherOtherClass`, in that a `Device` object can be used everywhere that an `OtherOtherClass` object can be used.  But yes, technically it is more like it *contains* or *consists-of* an `OtherOtherClass` within it. So when passing a `Device*` where a `OtherOtherClass*` is expected, the compiler will make the necessary adjustment automatically, yes. For instance, `this->socket.Init(this);` is implemented by the compiler *roughly equivalent* to `this->socket.Init(reinterpret_cast<OtherOtherClass*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this) + offsetof(Device, OtherOtherClass)));`